# Defining a global macro for all projects in Qt project tree

Tags: c++, qt, build, qmake

Suppose, I have a project with structure like this:

```
/project
|--- root.pro
   |--- app
   |    |--- app.pro
   |    `--- ... (source files of app)
   |--- test
   |    |--- test.pro
   |    `--- ... (source files of test)
```

The root.pro contains `SUBDIRS += project test`. I want to test code that uses conditional inclusion. So I want to add my own global define in root project to compile application and test the same way. I assume that I can do that via `DEFINES += MY_DEFINE` in my root.pro, but it doesn't work.

So the question is: how to define global macro to use it in application project and test project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create a file that you include from all your projects. For example in `include.mk` in the root directory:

```
DEFINES += MY_DEFINE
```

Then in each project:

```
include("../include.mk")
```